# What's the best way send email from the database in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sendmail

Migrating a legacy database from SQL Server 2000, and there are a few scheduled tasks that use `SP_OACreate` & `CDOSYS` to send emails to an open SMTP relay as in this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312839

In SQL Server 2008 R2, what's the best (simplest) way to replace the sendmail functionality? It seems like [DB Mail](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLServer2008DatabaseMail.aspx) is the new best recommended way, anyone have much experience with it or another alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DB Mail is by far the best way: it's simple SMTP.

Don't think about using:

- sp_OA% and cdosys (sp_OA% can be tricky and leak resources)
- xp_sendmail (require local Outlook install for MAPI client)

Comment: thanks, all the answers were pretty similar but I accepted yours as you addressed the deficiencies of the alternatives as well. cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Setup the SQL Server using DB Mail. It is fairly simple and uses SQL Service broker to manage messages - which means you don't lose mail if you can't connect to the SMTP server.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I use `sp_send_dbmail` primarily for sending mail within SQL Server, and it seems to be easy enough to set up and a reliable option, with plenty of configuration available.